# Calculating the average per day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, average

I want to calculate the average per day but in a monthly table.

My data looks like this:

```
ID      order   col1    col2    col3    date1       date2       user    category
ID_1    Order1  data1   data2   data100 2022-06-19  2021-10-10  User1   HR
ID_2    Order2  data1   data3   data101 2022-07-26  2022-01-13  User1   HR
ID_3    Order3  data1   data4   data102 2022-02-17  2022-02-17  User1   HR
ID_4    Order4  data1   data5   data103 2022-02-17  2022-02-20  User1   HR
ID_5    Order5  data1   data6   data104 2022-02-21  2022-02-21  User1   HR
ID_6    Order6  data1   data7   data105 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User1   Purchasing
ID_7    Order7  data1   data8   data106 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User1   Purchasing
ID_8    Order8  data1   data9   data107 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User1   Purchasing
ID_9    Order9  data1   data10  data108 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User1   Purchasing
ID_10   Order10 data1   data11  data109 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User2   Purchasing
ID_11   Order11 data1   data12  data110 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User2   Purchasing
ID_12   Order12 data1   data13  data111 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User2   Admin
ID_13   Order13 data1   data14  data112 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User3   Admin
ID_14   Order14 data1   data15  data113 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User3   Admin
ID_15   Order15 data1   data16  data114 2022-02-21  2022-02-23  User3   Admin
ID_16   Order16 data1   data17  data115 2022-02-23  2022-02-23  User3   Admin
ID_17   Order17 data1   data18  data116 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User4   Purchasing
ID_18   Order18 data1   data19  data117 2022-03-04  2022-03-06  User4   Purchasing
ID_19   Order19 data1   data20  data118 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User4   Admin
ID_20   Order20 data1   data21  data119 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User4   Admin
ID_21   Order21 data1   data22  data120 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User4   Admin
ID_22   Order22 data1   data23  data121 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   HR
ID_23   Order23 data1   data24  data122 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   HR
ID_24   Order24 data1   data25  data123 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   HR
ID_25   Order25 data1   data26  data124 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   Admin
ID_26   Order26 data1   data27  data125 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   Admin
ID_27   Order27 data1   data28  data126 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   Purchasing
ID_28   Order28 data1   data29  data127 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   Purchasing
ID_29   Order29 data1   data30  data128 2022-03-06  2022-03-06  User5   Purchasing
```

My output is:

```
user    category    January February    March   April   May June    July    August
User1   HR          0       3 | 1.0     0       0       0   0       0       0
        Purchasing  0       4 | 0.0     0       0       0   0       0       0
User2   Admin       0       1 | 0.0     0       0       0   0       0       0
        Purchasing  0       2 | 0.0     0       0       0   0       0       0
User3   Admin       0       4 | 0.5     0       0       0   0       0       0
User4   Admin       0       0           3 | 0.0 0       0   0       0       0
        Purchasing  0       0           2 | 1.0 0       0   0       0       0
User5   Admin       0       0           2 | 0.0 0       0   0       0       0
        HR          0       0           3 | 0.0 0       0   0       0       0
        Purchasing  0       0           3 | 0.0 0       0   0       0       0
```

In each month column first value indicates the count and second value indicates the average per month.

My code looks like this:

```
df1= pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
for i in range(1,13):
    m = str(i).zfill(2)
    start_date = '2022-'+str(m)+'-01'
    end_date = '2022-'+str(m)+'-31'

    mask = (df1['date1'] >= start_date) & (df1['date2'] <= end_date)
    df2 = df1.loc[mask]
    df2.date1 = pd.to_datetime(df2.date1)
    df2.date2 = pd.to_datetime(df2.date2)
    df2.drop(df2[df2.date2 < df2.date1].index, inplace=True)

    df2["days"] = (df2['date2'] - df2['date1']).dt.days
    combinations = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby(['user','category'])
     .agg({'order':'count', 'days': 'mean'})
    )
    combinations['order'] = combinations['order'].astype(str)
    combinations['days'] = combinations['days'].astype(str)
    combinations["agg"]= combinations["order"].str.cat(combinations["days"], sep =" | ")
    combinations=combinations.drop(['order', 'days'], axis=1)
    if (i==1):
        final_df=combinations
    else:
        final_df=final_df.merge(combinations, how='outer', on=['user','category'])

final_df = final_df.fillna(0)
final_df.columns =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','Novemeber','December']
display(final_df)
```

My code gives me the average per month but I want to get average per day in each column of month. (How much average orders per day have been received in this month?)

********* EDITED ***********

My final output should look like the same as my current output except replacing the value of average per month to average per days (after the "|").

Thanks,

Comment: How looks expected output from sample data?

Comment: I think ouput with numbers.

Comment: I ask because use `.agg({'order':'count', 'days': 'mean'})` - it return average days per month, but no idea what is `average per days`

Comment: Yes, the output with the numbers. As if how many on average orders are received in an average day). Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Now it's giving me the total count of the month but I want the average count per day.

Comment: How looks expected output from sample data with numbers?

Comment: The same only to replace the total count of month with the average per day followed by the "|" sign.

Comment: how is changed `3 | 1.0` ?

Comment: or `4 | 0.5` if `the total count of month with the average per day followed by the "|" sign.` ?

Comment: The output: `3 | 1.0` means that `Total count in month | average days taken`. I want `average no. of orders received per day | average days taken `

Comment: OK, seems not understand. I need to know how is changed data not only by description (I want average no. of orders received per day), but exactly with numbers. It means for February now get `'3 | 1.0', '4 | 0.0', '1 | 0.0', '2 | 0.0', '4 | 0.5'`, but what is expected ouput? Like `'0.783 | 1.0', '0.7584 | 0.0', '0.7841 | 0.0', '0.2572 | 0.0', '0.4444 | 0.5'` - Please change numbers by real data.

Comment: Or better what is formula for get `average no. of orders received per day` ?

Comment: Not with absolute numbers, it has to be float... As we are calculating the average no. of orders received.

Comment: Is problem create expected ouput with numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250859/discussion-between-soosa-and-jezrael).